# Bookmarklet grabs Youtube URL and goes to another website

Tags: javascript, youtube, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet to get video id of current youtube url and go to a website with the video id in the query string. `location.href` helps me to get current url.

```
    javascript:location.href='http://www.sampledomaincom/mybookmarkutility.html?v='+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
```

How to get video ID directly from url and append it to this query string as `+'&videoid='+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a **bookmarklet** to: *get video ID directly from url and append it to this query string as `+'&videoid='+`*.

`window.location.search` gives us the search-part. We strip of the leading `?`, split it by `&` and finally split every resulting value by `=`. If now there is an identifier `v` then we continue (using it's value), otherwise we alert an error..
Now let's apply this, re-factor the code and put it in an IIF (to overcome a lot of problems):

```
// alert edition:
javascript:(function(L,t,i){for(i=(t=L.search.slice(1).split('&')).length;i--&&(t[i]=t[i].split('='))[0]!=='v';);~i&&(t=t[i][1])?alert('http://www.sampledomain.com/mybookmarkutility.html?v='+encodeURIComponent(L.href)+'&videoid='+t):alert('No videoID found.')})(window.location);

// working edition:
javascript:(function(L,t,i){for(i=(t=L.search.slice(1).split('&')).length;i--&&(t[i]=t[i].split('='))[0]!=='v';);~i&&(t=t[i][1])?L.href='http://www.sampledomain.com/mybookmarkutility.html?v='+encodeURIComponent(L.href)+'&videoid='+t:alert('No videoID found.')})(window.location);
```

And an updated regex-version (it's a bit shorter):

```
// alert edition:
javascript:(function(L,t){(t=/[?&]v=([^&]+)/.exec(L.search))?alert('http://www.sampledomain.com/mybookmarkutility.html?v='+encodeURIComponent(L.href)+'&videoid='+t[1]):alert('No videoID found.')})(window.location);

// working edition:
javascript:(function(L,t){(t=/[?&]v=([^&]+)/.exec(L.search))?L.href='http://www.sampledomain.com/mybookmarkutility.html?v='+encodeURIComponent(L.href)+'&videoid='+t[1]:alert('No videoID found.')})(window.location);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a lazy answer for a lazy question. Your regex fails for 'v=xyz' and for 'v=xyz-2&a=b'. It also fails for a more theoretical case like 'sav=y&v=xyz'. (For posterity, in case the regex is changed later, the regex in the current answer is `/v=(\w*)&/`.)

Comment: @DG: You are right about the `-` character (I didn't realise YT used that) and the theoretical fails. I just can't reproduce the `v=xyz`-fail. Anyway, out with the regex, in with a robuster routine. I just can't get it smaller while constraining myself to ES3 (not using map etc). Thanks for giving me a chance to redeem myself before downvoting.